# Alinear checkboxes como tabla

Tags: html, css

He estado hoy intentado construir este formulario, pero hay algo que no puedo lograr:

[image: Alinear los checkboxes así]

He puesto `vertical align`, `float` y he probado distintas cosas de las que no tengo imágenes, agradecería algo de ayuda ya que no he podido lograrlo.

Actualmente mi formulario se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código:

```html
<div>
  <label class="label">HOBBIES:</label>
  <ul>
    
      <div id="checkboxes">
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="leer" value="leer"> <label for="leer">Leer</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="internet" value="internet"> <label for="internet">Internet</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="radio" value="radio"> <label for="radio">Radio</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="playstation" value="playstation"> <label for="playstation">Play Station</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="tv" value="tv"> <label for="tv">Television</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="callofduty" value="callofduty"> <label for="callofduty">Call of Duty</label> </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Agrega por favor el código que has estado desarrollando.

Comment: hola, gracias por su sugerencia, una consulta, como puedo añadir imagenes ahora, ya que el codigo es muy largo para este campo.

Comment: Es mejor el código para reproducir tu problema, solo aquel fragmento que sea relevante, por favor no uses imágenes salvo que sea necesario

Comment: eso es el html.

Comment: El código va en la pregunta , no en los comentarios. Ya lo he puesto yo por tí, recuérdalo para la próxima vez. Borra también los comentarios con el HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba de esta manera:

```html
<div>
  <div id="checkboxes1" style="display:inline-block">
    <ul>
      <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="leer" value="leer"> <label for="leer">Leer</label> </li>
      <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="internet" value="internet"> <label for="internet">Internet</label> </li>
      <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="radio" value="radio"> <label for="radio">Radio</label> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="checkboxes2" style="display:inline-block">
    <ul>
      <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="playstation" value="playstation"> <label for="playstation">Play Station</label> </li>
      <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="tv" value="tv"> <label for="tv">Television</label> </li>
      <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="callofduty" value="callofduty"> <label for="callofduty">Call of Duty</label> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Los estilos "inline" también los podrías definir a través de CSS:

```css
    .checkbox-style {
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div>    
    <div id="checkboxes1" class="checkbox-style">
        <ul>
            <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="leer" value="leer"> <label for="leer">Leer</label> </li>
            <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="internet" value="internet"> <label for="internet">Internet</label> </li>
            <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="radio" value="radio"> <label for="radio">Radio</label> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes2" class="checkbox-style">
        <ul>
            <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="playstation" value="playstation"> <label for="playstation">Play Station</label> </li>
            <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="tv" value="tv"> <label for="tv">Television</label> </li>
            <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="callofduty" value="callofduty"> <label for="callofduty">Call of Duty</label> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Explicación

- Dividí los 6 `checkboxes` en 2 grupos de 3 y a cada uno le asigne una `class="tres"`
- La leyenda de **HOBBIES** la puse en un tercer `div` con la `class="tres"`
- Los 3 `div` anteriores los envuelvo en uno principal con el `id="container"`
- Al contenedor principal le aplico un `display: flex;`
- Aplicamos un ancho para los elementos que tienen la clase `tres` de `50vw`
- Usé la pseudoclase `nth-child` solo para colocar un color e identificar visualmente el acomodo de los elementos

```html
    <style>
      li{
        list-style: none;
      }
      div#container{
        display: flex;
        border: solid 1px red;
      }
      .tres{
        width: 50vw;
      }
       /*estos son opcionales*/
      .tres:nth-child(even){
        background-color: pink;
      }
      .tres:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: crimson;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="tres">
        <h3>HOBBIES</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="tres">
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="leer" value="leer"> <label for="leer">Leer</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="internet" value="internet"> <label for="internet">Internet</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="radio" value="radio"> <label for="radio">Radio</label> </li>
      </div>
      <div class="tres">
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="playstation" value="playstation"> <label for="playstation">Play Station</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="tv" value="tv"> <label for="tv">Television</label> </li>
        <li> <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" id="callofduty" value="callofduty"> <label for="callofduty">Call of Duty</label> </li>
      </div>
    </div>
```